# how to use linq dynamic select based on type

Tags: c#, .net, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have below class mechanicalData like

```
public class MechanicalData
{
    public List<LibraryLighting> InternalLoadsLighting { get; set; }
    public List<LibraryEquipment> InternalLoadsEquipment { get; set; }
}
```

and then i am mapping the fields and forming a list object like as below

```
private static MechanicalData TransformMechanicalData(MechanicalData sourceMechanicalData, Dictionary<string, MasterSection> masterSectionMappedLibrary)
{
    return new MechanicalData()
    {
        InternalLoadsLighting = sourceMechanicalData.InternalLoadsLighting
                               .Where(a => a != null)
                               .Select(libraryLighting => new LibraryLighting
        {
            Id = libraryLighting.Id,
            IsApproved = true,
            Revision = libraryLighting.Revision,
            MasterSection = masterSectionMappedLibrary["Library Lighting"],
            SourceOfDataId = libraryLighting.SourceOfData.Id,
            LightingDensity = libraryLighting.LightingDensity
            .....
        }).ToList() ?? new(),

        InternalLoadsEquipment = sourceMechanicalData.InternalLoadsEquipment
                                 .Where(a => a != null)
                                 .Select(libraryEquipment => new LibraryEquipment
        {
            MasterSection = masterSectionMappedLibrary["Library Equipment"],
            SourceOfData = libraryEquipment.SourceOfData,
            EquipmentDensity = libraryEquipment.EquipmentDensity,
            Id = libraryEquipment.Id,
            IsApproved = true,
            Revision = libraryEquipment.Revision,
            ......
            ....
        }).ToList() ?? new(),
     }
 }
```

Is there any way i can apply dynamic type to simplify the above values assign or any suggestion with linq dynamic select query using reflection method that would be very grateful to me, TIA.

Comment: any one please suggest idea on this

Comment: It depends on what you mean by 'simplify'. Using AutoMapper or creating an Extension method to map the properties may help.

Comment: I cannot use automapper but i can use extension methods and looking for dynamic select linq as well

Comment: Could any one please help or suggestion how to call dynamic select on this

Answer (score -1):

What you basically want to do here is static a LINQ query dynamically. To do this, you need to modify/build the expression tree at runtime. If you are not familiar with expression trees and the `Expression<T>` type I recommend this article and the referenced pages in the "See also" section:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx

Comment: That is where i am stuck in, can you please suggest any kind of example that uses the dynamic select query